# C++ read() from ifstream: without pointers?

Tags: c++, pointers, ifstream

Suppose I have a struct and a file with binary representations of those structs and I'll make a function/method that access this binary data using `ifstream::read()`.

Here's an example struct:

```
struct MyStruct {
    int x; //Value interested in
    int y; //Value interested in
    int anotherInteger; //Not interested
    double aDouble; //Not interested
}
```

How do I make the function (I'll call it here readData) either: not using pointers when reading or, if using pointers is necessary, where would I put the proper delete?

So far, the relevant part of my readData looks like this:

```
void readData(int position, int &returnX, int &returnY) {
    ifstream inFile("binaryFile.dat",ios::binary);

    MyStruct *st = new MyStruct[1];

    inFile.seekg(sizeof(MyStruct)*pos);
    inFile.read((char*) st, sizeof(MyStruct));

    returnX = st[0].x;
    returnY = st[0].y;

    //delete [] st goes here?
}
```

I've tried uncommenting the delete part, but I get an allocation error, probably because the values of x and y are pointing to something that doesn't exist anymore.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why wouldn't you use a local variable?

```
void readData(int position, int &returnX, int &returnY) {
    ifstream inFile("binaryFile.dat",ios::binary);
    inFile.seekg(sizeof(MyStruct)*position);

    MyStruct st;    
    inFile.read((char*) &st, sizeof(MyStruct));

    returnX = st.x;
    returnY = st.y;
}

int main() {
    int mainx, mainy;
    readData(0, mainx, mainy);
    return 0;
}
```

Also, references cannot be re-seated.  Therefore the assignment assigns the value to the *origional* `int` passed by the calling function.  `returnX` and `returnY` are *not* pointed at the local variables.  In the code above, the assignment changes `mainx` and `mainy`.

Answer (score 2):

The simpler way it's to use a local variable:

```
void readData(int position, int &returnX, int &returnY) {
    ifstream inFile("binaryFile.dat",ios::binary);

    MyStruct st;

    inFile.seekg(sizeof(MyStruct)*position);
    inFile.read((char*)&st, sizeof(MyStruct));

    returnX = st.x;
    returnY = st.y;
}
```

Comment: I've tried this (even on a new separate code) and I'm still getting segmentation fault.

Comment: @luishenrique.ln: it shouldn't segfault.  Can we see the calling function?

Comment: The calling function is exactly like yours @MooingDuck. `readData(0,mainX,mainY);`

Comment: @luishenrique.ln: It shouldn't segfault.  What line is the segfault happening on.  Can you step into it and tell us?

Comment: The segfault occurs after the function readData ends and goes back to main. I tried generating another binary file and this solution you provided worked fine, so I think it can be related to the binary data creation. Thanks anyway. (sorry, can't give +rep)

Answer (score -1):

The `delete[]` is fine. If you get an error, it's not because the values of x and y are pointing to something that doesn't exist anymore since their values are just integers and don't point to anything.